# How to rebuild from regular expression with sed or awk command?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Hi I want to create insert command with sed from regular expression. Like this:

Regex:

```
   0  M 63823170268                         1C:1A:C0:20:07:BD 4d6h40m1s           
  10  M C2W0T979L                           2C:8A:72:D8:2F:81 4d6h40m1s           
 100  M PP2275468                           50:EA:D6:AB:61:EE 4d6h40m1s
```

I want to get like this:

```
insert into users(user, mac) select  '63823170268','1C:1A:C0:20:07:BD' from dual where not exists ( select  user  from users where user = '63823170268' and mac = '1C:1A:C0:20:07:BD' );
insert into users(user, mac) select  'C2W0T979L','2C:8A:72:D8:2F:81' from dual where not exists ( select  user  from users where user = 'C2W0T979L' and mac = '3C:C2:43:6D:EB:18' );
insert into users(user, mac) select  'PP2275468','50:EA:D6:AB:61:EE' from dual where not exists ( select  user  from users where user = 'PP2275468' and mac = '50:EA:D6:AB:61:EE' );
```

Comment: Does "many line" represent additional data in the same format that should also be processed in the same manner, or is it extraneous data that should be skipped?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? How should the lines that you want to change be distinguished from the ones that should remain the same? Please [edit] your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand on this example:

```
$ awk '{printf "foo \047%s\047,\047%s\047 bar\n",$3,$4}' file
foo '63823170268','1C:1A:C0:20:07:BD' bar
foo 'C2W0T979L','2C:8A:72:D8:2F:81' bar
foo 'PP2275468','50:EA:D6:AB:61:EE' bar
```